# How to bind Entity Framework 6 to KendoUI Grid

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have created a test SQL Server database with two tables: WorkItem and WorkItemNote.  There is a foreign key between them such that one WorkItem can have many WorkItemNote records.
I am trying to display the WorkItems in a Kendo Grid.  The Action is returning Json, but nothing is displayed in the grid.
If I create an anonymous object with just the properties I want to display, it works.
That indicates that an Entity (WorkItem) that has a relationship (WorkItemNote) cannot be displayed in a Kendo Grid.
Is there any way around this?

My Grid:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TryToLoadGrid.Models.WorkItem>()
        .Name("grid")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:380px;" } )
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("GetActiveWorkItems", "Home")))
        .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(workItem => workItem.Title);
                columns.Bound(workItem => workItem.Description);
            }
        )
    )
</div>
```

My action code is:

```
 public ActionResult GetActiveWorkItems([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
 {
     using (TaskManagerContext context = new TaskManagerContext())
     {
         IQueryable<WorkItem> list = context.WorkItems.Where(x => x.IsActive == true);
         DataSourceResult result = list.ToDataSourceResult(request);
         return Json(result);
     }
 }
```

As you can see from my Action that I'm not even interested in the WorkItemNotes for the grid.

As proof that it is due to the relationship, I created this second Action which does work and display data:

```
  public ActionResult GetActiveWorkItems2([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
  {
      using (TaskManagerContext context = new TaskManagerContext())
      {
          List<WorkItem> list = context.WorkItems.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList();
          List<Object> dataObjects = new List<object>();
          foreach (WorkItem workItem in list)
          {
              dataObjects.Add(new { Title = workItem.Title, Description = workItem.Description });
          }

          DataSourceResult result = dataObjects.ToDataSourceResult(request);
          return Json(result);
      }
  }
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I think it's a bad practice to use Entity Framework models directly in your UI. You should extract the data you require from your model and place that in a view model. Then you return your list of view models to the client.

```
public class WorkItemViewModel 
{
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set }
    public string Desctription { get; set }
}


public ActionResult GetActiveWorkItems2([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    using (TaskManagerContext context = new TaskManagerContext())
    {
        List<WorkItem> list = context.WorkItems.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList();
        List<WorkItemViewModel> dataObjects = new List<WorkItemViewModel>();
        foreach (WorkItem workItem in list)
        {
            dataObjects.Add(new WorkItemViewModel { Title = workItem.Title, Description = workItem.Description });
        }
        return Json(dataObjects.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
}


<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModelNamespace.WorkItemViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:380px;" } )
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("GetActiveWorkItems", "Home")))
        .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(workItem => workItem.ID).Hidden();
                columns.Bound(workItem => workItem.Title);
                columns.Bound(workItem => workItem.Description);
            }
        )
    )
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would avoid using EF entities directly?  Are there possible side effects?   Or do you feel it is simply bad style?

Comment: I like my view models having a 1:1 relationship with the views/controls. That prevents side effects you're experiencing now (since using entities doesn't work in your case) and generally makes data representation easier because you're flattening the data structures. It also allows you to loosly couple your data access layer and your UI.

Comment: Thank you Nic.  That's exactly the clarification was I was looking for.

Comment: Does this mean that you load every single `WorkItem` into memory instead of letting the `ToDataSourceResult` do the hard work against the DB first with its sorting, filtering, etc?

Comment: I guess it depends on how many of those objects you have. You can always use `AsQueryable()` instead of `ToList()`, and apply the filtering on the database using `ToDataSourceResult`.